# NURBS library for Delphi

Tags: delphi, nurbs, splines

Could you recommend some library to manipulate splines available for Delphi? I've done some searching but all I've found had C/C++/Python bindings. The features I need are: manipulating splines in 2D: rotate, translate, mirror, scale
and also intersecting, inserting knots, interpolating spline with polyline.

#### Edit:

GLScene **is not** what I am looking for as I need **only** support for 2D splines and not for 3D surfaces. Also I don't want the library to be sticked with rendering engine. I want to perform certain calculations and GLScene does not fit my needs.

Comment: 'http://www.sulaco.co.za/opengl_project_NURBS_%20Non-Uniform_Rational_B-Spline.htm' and 'http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage' might be useful

Answer (score 2):

[GlScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage) is a good library to do NURBS take a look at this http://glscene.pbworks.com/w/page/6437577/doc_demosmeshes

There is a duck NURBS example here... good luck...